# Java Regex behaves not logical. replace words within text

Tags: java, regex, replace

I dont understand, why this regex does not replace "dürfen" ... 
I have an input text and need to replace a lot of fillwords. but some are ignored for some reason. This has to do something with the spaces, but i dont get it.

```
    String input = "melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl darüber das volksfestmadl stadt freising dürfen begeistern für tanzsport ";
    //does not work
    input = input.replaceAll("( dürfen )", " ");
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\sdürfen\\s)", " ");
    input = input.replace(" dürfen ", " ");

    //works ...
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\sdarüber\\s)", " ");
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\smöchte\\s)", " ");
    //input = input.replace(" dürfen", " "); //works but is not desired ...
    System.out.println(input);
```

Output

> melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl das volksfestmadl stadt
>   freising dürfen begeistern für tanzsport

Expected is that "dürfen" is not part of the output .. but it is! On the other Hand "darüber" is vanished ...

Comment: Use `\b` to check for work boundary.

Comment: [Runnable](http://runnable.com/me/VLH3t57g66kJzRU6) works without the umlauts; can you try your code without them?  Could be an encoding thing.

Comment: FWIW, your code replaces "dürfen" as you expect in my [Ideone test](http://ideone.com/HtWBq9).

Comment: thank you @J0e3gan then this is indeed buggy only on my pc / java version whatever reason. like i said... it does not really makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works (theres no problem with umlauted letters) and its regex leaves the string with correct spacing:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\W*\\bdürfen\\b\\W*", " ").trim();
```

The small distinction with this regex is that it consumes any non-word chars (ie hyphens etc, not just whitespace) either side and puts in a space. This result is then trimmed to deal with the edge case of the substitution occurring at the start/end of the input.

Comment: thank you ... boundaries \b works much better than \s ... but i quite dont understand why most of the words work, but some not ...

Comment: @Umingo your "not working" examples worked for me. Check the encoding of your editor. Alternatively, code your literals using UTF format, eg `ü` is `\u00fc`

Comment: thx @Bogemian, but the strange thing is, that there is nothing else as UTF-8. I am working with netbeans and netbeans refuses to work with files encodes other than utf-8

Comment: You might have characters from another charset - that look the same but are different - somewhere: print out the decimal value of each character: `System.out.println((int)str.charAt(i));` and compare

Answer (score 0):

This works in python...

```
# coding: utf-8

import re
s = "melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl darüber das volksfestmadl stadt freising dürfen begeistern für tanzsport "
print(re.sub(' dürfen ','',s))
# melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl darüber das volksfestmadl stadt freisingbegeistern für tanzsport
```

Try only substututing `" dürfen "` instead of `"( dürfen )"` or `"(\\sdürfen\\s)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that your regex is including space on either side of the search word. After regex engines replaces one instance of the word `" dürfen "`, it leaves no space for words on left and right hand sides. Hence next word replacement fails (due to not availability of spaces before word).

You can use lookahead regex to fix this:

```
String input = "melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl darüber das volksfestmadl stadt freising dürfen begeistern für tanzsport ";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+(dürfen|darüber|möchte)(?=\\s)", "");
System.out.println( input );
//=> melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl das volksfestmadl stadt freising begeistern für tanzsport
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue and your code works fine.

---

package com.stackoverflow;

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String input = "melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl darüber das volksfestmadl stadt freising dürfen begeistern für tanzsport ";
    //does not work
    input = input.replaceAll("( dürfen )", " ");
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\sdürfen\\s)", " ");
    input = input.replace(" dürfen ", " ");

    //works ...
    //input = input.replaceAll("(\\sdarüber\\s)", " ");
    //input = input.replaceAll("(\\smöchte\\s)", " ");
    //input = input.replace(" dürfen", " "); //works but is not desired ...
    System.out.println(input);

}
```

}

---

Output

melanie rugullies eching trägt dirndl darüber das volksfestmadl stadt freising begeistern für tanzsport